# What are the exclusions for using a very long and random password?

Tags: passwords

It is a good practise to always use long (63 character) and random passwords.

**Question:** But what are the exclusions? Can someone mention cases?

Example: when console login is needed (so not via SSH, but by a human by psychically typing the password in it at a server room via keyboard). What are the other examples, whe na 63 char password couldn't be typed in in a reasonable time?

Comment: Too broad. Anytime it's a usability problem. Example: first-generation Minuteman PALs (yeah, those with the ridiculously standard PIN).

Comment: Nice typo you have: _psychically_ typing the password.

Comment: typo? why? I can type the password via ssh too

Comment: [physically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/physically) vs [psychically](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/psychically)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if making passwords longer and longer increases the security. A password over 20 chars with random(!) digits, symbols and letters is extremely hard to remember for the normal person.

Therefore I think by using 63 letters you're either

- using a password manager
- write the password down
- use only this long password as a master password everywhere (since you learned to remember it)
- the password consists of random word combinations, that might be susceptible for dictionary attacks

All of those approaches have their advantages / disadvantages.

As [Deer Hunter](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/13820/deer-hunter) mentioned, most of the problems of very long passwords are on the usability side. Typing a password, hitting enter and then re-type the password due to a typo takes a lot of time. If you're in a datacenter and need to log into many machines per day, you soon will go back to using shorter passwords or find other solutions.

Also there are times, when a simple password is okay i.e. on temporary services. If I want to register an anonymous email, it's okay to use a simple / short password, as I will never use this email adress again.